# Galaxy S4 - Cannot turn email notifications OFF

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4, email

Probably after a software upgrade, my phone now vibrates and makes a sound whenever an email comes in.  This is annoying and keeps me up at night!  I have unchecked email notifications but it hasn't stopped.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What email app are you using? The Samsung one that comes on the phone, or Gmail, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

go to settings, find aplications menu find your e-mail client that spams notifications, click it. you will find buttons like uninstall or delete app's data. there should be a checkbox for notifications. you can disable them. now app dosent have permission to throw any notifications on you